# How to push notification in background on Expo app?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

I would like to know how to code the sending of notifications in an Expo application (React Native) and which modules to use for this purpose. I've tried using FCM, but without success. My goal is to send notifications even when the application is running in the background, or even when it's closed.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.